# Optimizing Rust Code for Creating a Thousand Nested References Without Recursion Error or Performance Issues

Tags: rust, ffi

I recently came across an interesting article ([How to Become a 1000 Stars Programmer](https://medium.com/@iiixphillxiii/how-to-become-a-1000-stars-programmer-0d810cdea998)) that discusses the concept of a "1000-star programmer". Inspired by this, I attempted to RIIR a piece of code from the article.

My goal is to create a Rust program that generates a thousand nested references. However, I'm encountering challenges with my current implementations.

The first version

```rust
/// Generates nested references to an integer and prints the value of the original integer.
/// 
/// # Arguments
/// 
/// * `$n` - The depth of nested references to create.
macro_rules! generate_and_print_nested_refs {
    ($n:expr) => {{
        let mut code = String::new();
        code.push_str("fn main() {\n    // Initialize the base variable\n");
        code.push_str("    let i0 = 42;\n\n    // Create nested references\n");

        for i in 1..=$n {
            let amps = "&".repeat(i);
            code.push_str(&format!("    let i{} = {}i{}; // Level {}\n", i, amps, i - 1, i));
        }

        code.push_str("\n    // Print the value of the deepest reference\n");
        code.push_str(&format!("    println!(\"{}\", *i{});\n", "{}", $n));
        code.push_str("}\n");

        code
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let code = generate_and_print_nested_refs!(1000);
    println!("{}", code);
}
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb5f044caf46d480afd7e263cc9d9ec1)) seems to fail due to recursive displays. The second version

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_int};

extern "C" {
    fn printf(format: *const c_char, ...) -> i32;
}

macro_rules! generate_and_print_nested_refs {
    ($n:expr) => {{
        let mut code = String::new();
        code.push_str("use std::ffi::CString;\n");
        code.push_str("use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_int};\n\n");
        code.push_str("extern \"C\" {\n    fn printf(format: *const c_char, ...) -> i32;\n}\n\n");
        code.push_str("fn main() {\n    // Initialize the base variable\n");
        code.push_str("    let i0 = 42;\n\n    // Create nested references\n");

        for i in 1..=$n {
            let amps = "&".repeat(i);
            code.push_str(&format!("    let i{} = {}i{}; // Level {}\n", i, amps, i - 1, i));
        }

        code.push_str("\n    // Print the value of the deepest reference\n");
        let deref_str = "*".repeat($n * ($n + 1) / 2);
        code.push_str(&format!("    let value = {}i{};\n", deref_str, $n));
        code.push_str("    let c_string = CString::new(\"The answer is: %d\\n\").expect(\"CString::new failed\");\n");
        code.push_str("    unsafe {\n");
        code.push_str("        printf(c_string.as_ptr(), value as c_int);\n");
        code.push_str("    }\n");
        code.push_str("}\n");

        code
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let code = generate_and_print_nested_refs!(1000);
    println!("{}", code);
}
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=438660fd2a3d7b8fccb994199e5acbe1)) doesn't work properly even with a hundred references.

I'm looking for advice or suggestions on how to make a working version of this concept for a thousand nested references. The key challenges seem to be avoiding recursive display errors and ensuring the program can handle a large number of references without significant performance degradation.

Any insights or alternative approaches to achieve this in Rust would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please note that [providing a link to your site is not sufficient](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428). Paste your code here as text so as to make a [mre].

Comment: Both your playground links generate the same problematic code, you are increasing the number of references `&&&&...` *on top of* the prior reference. This would not create a 1000-deep reference, but rather a 1000!-deep reference (1000 factorial =~ 4x10^2568). Your code just needs `let i8 = &i7;` to accomplish that, not `let i8 = &&&&&&&&i7;`. Like this: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=62b37f42c621e09097bc325e86342d24).

Comment: @kmdreko yeah, but I think it's not a 1000!, only sum of first n, where n = 1000

Comment: Ah, you're right. I got hasty with my thinking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like said @kmdreko, I generate too many references.
Correct code with 1000 asterisks generated by this:

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_int};

extern "C" {
    fn printf(format: *const c_char, ...) -> i32;
}

macro_rules! generate_and_print_nested_refs {
    ($n:expr) => {{
        let mut code = String::new();
        code.push_str("use std::ffi::CString;\n");
        code.push_str("use std::os::raw::{c_char, c_int};\n\n");
        code.push_str("extern \"C\" {\n    fn printf(format: *const c_char, ...) -> i32;\n}\n\n");
        code.push_str("fn main() {\n    // Initialize the base variable\n");
        code.push_str("    let i0 = 42;\n\n    // Create nested references\n");

        for i in 1..=$n {
            code.push_str(&format!("    let i{} = {}i{}; // Level {}\n", i, "&", i - 1, i));
        }

        code.push_str("\n    // Print the value of the deepest reference\n");
        
        code.push_str(&format!("    let value = {}i{};\n", "*".repeat($n), $n));
        code.push_str("    let c_string = CString::new(\"The answer is: %d\\n\").expect(\"CString::new failed\");\n");
        code.push_str("    unsafe {\n");
        code.push_str("        printf(c_string.as_ptr(), value as c_int);\n");
        code.push_str("    }\n");
        code.push_str("}\n");

        code
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let code = generate_and_print_nested_refs!(1000);
    println!("{}", code);
}
```

Comment: please write what the solution is as well.